# JQuery Dialog box pop up through linkbuttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a link button. On clicking on the that linkbutton, I want a dialog box to pop up. I tried a lot but unable to proceed.

Following is the pieces of codes on how I am trying this.

in .cs file : (this is how I dynamically created the link button) (I have used lnkButtons class in my jquery.

```
LinkButton lnkUpdateComment = new LinkButton();
lnkUpdateComment.ID = "" + objBridgeNotes.BridgeNotesId;
lnkUpdateComment.Text = "edit";
lnkUpdateComment.Attributes.Add("class", "lnkButtons");
lnkUpdateComment.Click += new EventHandler(lnkUpdateComment_Click);
```

.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {

$(".lnkButtons").live("click", function()  {
$("#divEditComment").dialog("option", "title", "Edit the Comment");
$("#divEditComment").dialog("open");
return true;
});

$(function () {
var dlg = $("#divEditComment").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "blind",
    //height: 450,
    minWidth: 400,
    //position: ['right', 210],
    buttons: {
        "Update Note": function () {

            var Updates = btnSubmitComment.replace(/_/g, '$');
            __doPostBack(Updates, '');
        }
    }
});
dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
});

});
```

in .aspx file:

```
    <div id="divEditComment">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updComments" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <table width="100%" style="text-align: center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="divComments" runat="server">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work as expected?

Comment: no idea. It wont go inside the Jquery function at all.. I strongly believe some small change is missing. But unable to trigger. So posted here so that the Jquery experts can correct :)

Comment: @AlwynMiranda Check firebug Is there any issue thrown?

Comment: No firebug :(.. Actually in my office there is no firefox :( ... Cant get it installled tooo.. (due to some security reasons and bla bla)

Comment: @Andrei : No dialog box is popped up..

Comment: I installed Firebug.. No errors and warning found

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
    var dlg = $("#divEditComment").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        //height: 450,
        minWidth: 400,
        //position: ['right', 210],
        buttons: {
            "Update Note": function () {

                var Updates = btnSubmitComment.replace(/_/g, '$');
                __doPostBack(Updates, '');
            }
        }
    });
    dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    });

$(document).ready(function()  {

    $(".lnkButtons").live("click", function()  {
    $("#divEditComment").dialog("open");
    return false;
    });
    });
```

**.aspx**

```
     <div id="divEditComment" title="Edit the comment">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updComments" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <table width="100%" style="text-align: center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="divComments" runat="server">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the change in this?

Comment: @AlwynMiranda click function return false and directly assign title to the div and $(function(){.. move out from the document.ready

Comment: Did all as you said. Still no pop up.

Comment: @AlwynMiranda just place ur js code at end of you page.it is just a try only

Answer (score 0):

Just replace return true to return false. It will worked.

```
 $(document).ready(function()  {

$(".lnkButtons").live("click", function()  {
$("#divEditComment").dialog("option", "title", "Edit the Comment");
$("#divEditComment").dialog("open");
**return false;**
});

$(function () {
var dlg = $("#divEditComment").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "blind",
    //height: 450,
    minWidth: 400,
    //position: ['right', 210],
    buttons: {
        "Update Note": function () {

            var Updates = btnSubmitComment.replace(/_/g, '$');
            __doPostBack(Updates, '');
        }
    }
});
dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
});

});
```

------------------- **Update**---------------------

LinkButton lnkUpdateComment = new LinkButton();
            lnkUpdateComment.ID = "MyBtn" ;
            lnkUpdateComment.Text = "My name Is khan";
            lnkUpdateComment.Attributes.Add("class", "lnkButtons");
            YourPlaceholder.Controls.Add(lnkUpdateComment);
            lnkUpdateComment.Click += new EventHandler(lnkUpdateComment_Click);

```
$(".lnkButtons").live("click", function() {
        var dlg33 = $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Filter records",
            height: "450",
            width: "600",
            maxHeight: "450",
            maxWidth: "600",
            buttons: {
                "Update Note": function() {

                    var Updates = btnSubmitComment.replace(/_/g, '$');
                    __doPostBack(Updates, '');
                }
            }
            });
            dlg33.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
            return false;


        });
```

Comment: @Alwyn Miranda Do you bind your linkbutton with page or some placeholder?

Comment: No .. I dont use these dynamically created link buttons anywhere.. Since there are more than one link buttons I use class attribute (lnkUpdateComment.Attributes.Add("class", "lnkButtons"); ). And use "lnkButtons" in Jquery-> $(".lnkButtons").live("click", function() {... Brain is completely paralysed searching for bug since two days.  :0

Comment: hey all controls must be appear in page control's hierarchy, so firstly you bind your button with page or as i explained in a placeholder (you can hide it using display:none).. it worked properly. i have used above code in my many pages and worked perfectly...

Comment: problem is I have many no of buttons... So I need to create it dynamically and depending on the no of blogs.. And the new requirement is I need to add Edit linkbotton for each of the blogs and user on clicking it will pop up a dialog box. this pop up i am unable to achieve.